# How does fgetcsv( ) works under the hood?

Tags: php

I have developed some php code that reads a csv file (by means of fgetcsv() ), validates the (customised) header within the file, processes the following data payload and saves the results into a database. The code works fine, but has become very large as I did not break up the code into functions (all the mentioned actions are within the typical while loop as in the known first example of www.php.net/fgetcsv).

So I want to re-organise my code by breaking up in functions, in fact, defining a class with methods, and I was wondering whether I still need the while-loop for accessing the entire file, or whether I can use the fgetcsv() with the various methods like in the example below?: E.g. call fgetcsv() in the various methods after each other. I'm not sure whether fgetcsv() changes the value of the filehandler (pointer) when it has read a line, as I could not find this in the manual www.php.net/fgetcsv or else on this site.

simplified code example:

```
class Mycsvfile {

   $filehandle;

   function __construct($filename){} //opens the $file with a name; sets $filehandle

   function isValidHeader(){} //checks customised header; calls fgetcsv() 

   function processPayload(){} //processes the data payload after the header; calls fgetcsv() and database storage functions

   function close(){} //closes the csv file

}

$myfile = new Mycsvfile('aname');

if($myfile->isValidHeader){
  $myfile->processPayload();
}
$myfile->close();
```

Comment: I suggest creating an iterator to parse the file, check this comment in the docs for an exemple http://fr2.php.net/fgetcsv#57802, and Yes it does change the pointer

Comment: It doesn't do anything but read from the handle: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/ext/standard/file.c#L2037

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: thnx for all comments (!). @Blender: if it doesnt do anything, how does fgetcsv() determine what the next line is? (referring to the 'while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){}' example in php.net/fgetcsv)

Answer (score -1):

If all else fails, you can always look into the PHP source code.  I'm not an expert on the subject, but it looks like the workings of the `fgetcsv()` function are described in file `/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc` around line 77.  Here is a link to the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/internal/splfileobject.inc#L77

Comment: the link is no longer available